# Как отправить сообщение в центр уведомления Mac OS на Python?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

Я перепробовал около трех библиотек для этой цели и не одна из них не работает - не устанавливается библиотека или ошибка при выполнении. 
Самый простой способ и близкий к системе (насколько я понял) и часто встречающийся на форумах так это использование модуля [pyobjc](https://gist.github.com/lukaszb/5001170). Но этот модуль я не могу установить :

pip3 install pyobjc

> Install packages failed: Error
> occurred when installing package
> pyobjc.
>
> The following command was executed:
>
> packaging_tool.py install --build-dir
> /private/var/folders/g2/0ytb_hgx3yz1fcr6dwjdyw8h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging8684618905321973057.tmp
> pyobjc
>
> The error output of the command:
>
> DEPRECATION: --no-install,
> --no-download, --build, and --no-clean are deprecated.  See
> https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/906.
> Downloading/unpacking pyobjc
> Downloading pyobjc-2.5.1.tar.gz
> Running setup.py
> (path:/private/var/folders/g2/0ytb_hgx3yz1fcr6dwjdyw8h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging8684618905321973057.tmp/pyobjc/setup.py) egg_info for package pyobjc
>      Downloading/unpacking pyobjc-core==2.5.1 (from pyobjc)
> Running setup.py
> (path:/private/var/folders/g2/0ytb_hgx3yz1fcr6dwjdyw8h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging8684618905321973057.tmp/pyobjc-core/setup.py) egg_info for package pyobjc-core
>
> ```
> warning: no directories found matching 'Scripts'
> warning: no directories found matching 'setup-lib'
> warning: no directories found matching 'source-deps'
> warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found
> ```
>
> anywhere in distribution
>     warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere
> in distribution
>     warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere
> in distribution Downloading/unpacking
> pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.5.1
> (from pyobjc)   Downloading
> pyobjc-framework-AddressBook-2.5.1.tar.gz
> Running setup.py
> (path:/private/var/folders/g2/0ytb_hgx3yz1fcr6dwjdyw8h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging8684618905321973057.tmp/pyobjc-framework-AddressBook/setup.py)
> egg_info for package
> pyobjc-framework-AddressBook
>     warning: no directories found matching 'Scripts'
>     warning: no directories found matching 'setup-lib'
>     warning: no directories found matching 'source-deps'
>     warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found
> anywhere in distribution
>     warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere
> in distribution
>     warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere
> in distribution
>     libffi-src/ffi.c:107:1: warning: unused function 'struct_on_stack'
> [-Wunused-function]
>     struct_on_stack(
>     ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:551:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/fsref.m:212:1: warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/fsspec.m:138:1: warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/function.m:334:1: warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/informal-protocol.m:233:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/instance-var.m:453:1: warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/libffi_support.m:31:19:
> warning: unused variable
> 'gCFRangeEncoding'
> [-Wunused-const-variable]
>     static const char gCFRangeEncoding[1024] = { 0 };
>                       ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/method-accessor.m:468:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/method-imp.m:352:1: warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/method-signature.m:97:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/objc-class.m:1623:1: warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/objc-NULL.m:66:1: warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/objc-object.m:890:6: warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>          },
>          ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/objc_super.m:177:1: warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/objc_support.m:839:35:
> warning: sizeof on pointer operation
> will return size of 'char *' instead
> of 'char [19]' [-Wsizeof-array-decay]
>                             sizeof(@encode(struct sockaddr)-1)) ==
> 0) {
>                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
>     Modules/objc/objc_support.m:1114:77:
> warning: sizeof on pointer operation
> will return size of 'char* ' instead
> of 'char [19]' [-Wsizeof-array-decay]
>             if (strncmp(type, @encode(struct sockaddr),
> sizeof(@encode(struct sockaddr)-1)) ==
> 0) {
>                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
>     Modules/objc/objc_support.m:1504:78:
> warning: sizeof on pointer operation
> will return size of 'char *' instead
> of 'char [19]' [-Wsizeof-array-decay]
>             if (strncmp(types, @encode(struct sockaddr),
> sizeof(@encode(struct sockaddr)-1)) ==
> 0) {
>                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
>     3 warnings generated.
>     Modules/objc/ObjCPointer.m:134:1: warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/OC_PythonArray.m:356:34:
> warning: conflicting parameter types
> in implementation of
> 'initWithObjects:count:': 'const id* '
> vs 'NSObject **'
> [-Wmismatched-parameter-types]
>     -(id)initWithObjects:(NSObject**)objects
> count:(NSUInteger)count
>                           ~~~~~~~~~~ ^
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:93:46:
> note: previous definition is here
>     - (instancetype)initWithObjects:(const
> id [])objects count:(NSUInteger)cnt;
> / *designated initializer* /
>                                            ~~~~~ ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/OC_PythonDictionary.m:377:35:
> warning: conflicting parameter types
> in implementation of
> 'initWithObjects:forKeys:count:':
> 'const id *' vs 'NSObject **'
> [-Wmismatched-parameter-types]
>     - (id)initWithObjects:(NSObject**)objects
>                            ~~~~~~~~~~ ^
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSDictionary.h:70:46:
> note: previous definition is here
>     - (instancetype)initWithObjects:(const
> id [])objects forKeys:(const id
> <NSCopying> [])keys
> count:(NSUInteger)cnt;       /*
> designated initializer */
>                                            ~~~~~ ^
>     Modules/objc/OC_PythonDictionary.m:378:24:
> warning: conflicting parameter types
> in implementation of
> 'initWithObjects:forKeys:count:':
> 'const id<NSCopying>* ' vs 'NSObject
> **' [-Wmismatched-parameter-types]
>               forKeys:(NSObject**)keys
>                        ~~~~~~~~~~ ^
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSDictionary.h:70:87:
> note: previous definition is here
>     - (instancetype)initWithObjects:(const
> id [])objects forKeys:(const id
> <NSCopying> [])keys
> count:(NSUInteger)cnt;       /
> *designated initializer* /
>                                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
>     2 warnings generated.
>     Modules/objc/OC_PythonUnicode.m:297:27:
> warning: conflicting parameter types
> in implementation of
> 'initWithBytes:length:encoding:':
> 'const void *' vs 'void* '
> [-Wmismatched-parameter-types]
>     -(id)initWithBytes:(void*)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length
> encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
>                         ~~~~~ ^
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:265:45:
> note: previous definition is here
>     - (instancetype)initWithBytes:(const
> void* )bytes length:(NSUInteger)len
> encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
>                                          ~~~~~~ ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/selector.m:501:1: warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     Modules/objc/selector.m:772:1: warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     Modules/objc/selector.m:1855:1: warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     3 warnings generated.
>     Modules/objc/struct-wrapper.m:1095:5:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>         },
>         ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/unicode-object.m:205:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     Modules/objc/varlist.m:371:1: warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>     };
>     ^
>     1 warning generated.
>     ld: warning: could not create compact unwind for _ffi_call_unix64:
> does not use RBP or RSP based frame
>     Modules/objc/test/properties.m:24:9:
> warning: Ignore warnings about
> properties in this file.
> [-W#pragma-messages]
>     #pragma message "Ignore warnings about properties in this file."
>             ^
>     Modules/objc/test/properties.m:28:1:
> warning: no 'assign', 'retain', or
> 'copy' attribute is specified -
> 'assign' is assumed
> [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]
>     @property id prop4;
>     ^
>     Modules/objc/test/properties.m:28:1:
> warning: default property attribute
> 'assign' not appropriate for non-GC
> object [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]
>     Modules/objc/test/properties.m:30:1:
> warning: no 'assign', 'retain', or
> 'copy' attribute is specified -
> 'assign' is assumed
> [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]
>     @property(readwrite) id prop6;
>     ^
>     Modules/objc/test/properties.m:30:1:
> warning: default property attribute
> 'assign' not appropriate for non-GC
> object [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]
>     Modules/objc/test/properties.m:35:1:
> warning: no 'assign', 'retain', or
> 'copy' attribute is specified -
> 'assign' is assumed
> [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]
>     @property(getter=propGetter,setter=propSetter:)
> id prop11;
>     ^
>     Modules/objc/test/properties.m:35:1:
> warning: default property attribute
> 'assign' not appropriate for non-GC
> object [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]
>     7 warnings generated.
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
>       File "/private/var/folders/g2/0ytb_hgx3yz1fcr6dwjdyw8h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging8684618905321973057.tmp/pyobjc-framework-AddressBook/setup.py",
> line 33, in <module>
>         for fn in os.listdir('Modules')
>       File "/private/var/folders/g2/0ytb_hgx3yz1fcr6dwjdyw8h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging8684618905321973057.tmp/pyobjc-framework-AddressBook/pyobjc_setup.py",
> line 441, in setup
>         **k
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py",
> line 108, in setup
>         _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/dist.py",
> line 261, in **init**
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/dist.py",
> line 286, in fetch_build_eggs
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources.py",
> line 631, in resolve
>         dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources.py",
> line 871, in best_match
>         return self.obtain(req, installer)
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources.py",
> line 883, in obtain
>         return installer(requirement)
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/dist.py",
> line 337, in fetch_build_egg
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
> line 613, in easy_install
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
> line 643, in install_item
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
> line 833, in install_eggs
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
> line 1055, in build_and_install
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
> line 1040, in run_setup
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 50, in run_setup
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 100, in run
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 52, in <lambda>
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/compat.py",
> line 75, in execfile
>       File "setup.py", line 574, in <module>
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py",
> line 148, in setup
>         dist.run_commands()
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py",
> line 955, in run_commands
>         self.run_command(cmd)
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py",
> line 974, in run_command
>         cmd_obj.run()
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py",
> line 161, in run
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py",
> line 147, in call_command
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py",
> line 313, in run_command
>         self.distribution.run_command(command)
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py",
> line 974, in run_command
>         cmd_obj.run()
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/install_lib.py",
> line 10, in run
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 111, in install
>         outfiles = self.copy_tree(self.build_dir,
> self.install_dir)
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/install_lib.py",
> line 35, in copy_tree
>       File "setup.py", line 271, in get_exclusions
>     AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_install_lib'
>     Use '/usr/bin/clang' instead of 'clang' as the compiler
>     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>     warning: no directories found matching 'Scripts'
>
> warning: no directories found matching
> 'setup-lib'
>
> warning: no directories found matching
> 'source-deps'
>
> warning: no previously-included files
> matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in
> distribution
>
> warning: no previously-included files
> matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in
> distribution
>
> warning: no previously-included files
> matching '*.so' found anywhere in
> distribution
>
> libffi-src/ffi.c:107:1: warning:
> unused function 'struct_on_stack'
> [-Wunused-function]
>
> struct_on_stack(
>
> ^
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:551:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/fsref.m:212:1: warning:
> missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/fsspec.m:138:1: warning:
> missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/function.m:334:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/informal-protocol.m:233:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/instance-var.m:453:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/libffi_support.m:31:19:
> warning: unused variable
> 'gCFRangeEncoding'
> [-Wunused-const-variable]
>
> static const char
> gCFRangeEncoding[1024] = { 0 };
>
> ```
>               ^
> ```
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/method-accessor.m:468:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/method-imp.m:352:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/method-signature.m:97:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/objc-class.m:1623:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/objc-NULL.m:66:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/objc-object.m:890:6:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> ```
>  },
>
>  ^
> ```
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/objc_super.m:177:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/objc_support.m:839:35:
> warning: sizeof on pointer operation
> will return size of 'char *' instead
> of 'char [19]' [-Wsizeof-array-decay]
>
> ```
>                     sizeof(@encode(struct sockaddr)-1)) ==
> ```
>
> 0) {
>
> ```
>                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> ```
>
> Modules/objc/objc_support.m:1114:77:
> warning: sizeof on pointer operation
> will return size of 'char *' instead
> of 'char [19]' [-Wsizeof-array-decay]
>
> ```
>     if (strncmp(type, @encode(struct sockaddr),
> ```
>
> sizeof(@encode(struct sockaddr)-1)) ==
> 0) {
>
> ```
>                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> ```
>
> Modules/objc/objc_support.m:1504:78:
> warning: sizeof on pointer operation
> will return size of 'char *' instead
> of 'char [19]' [-Wsizeof-array-decay]
>
> ```
>     if (strncmp(types, @encode(struct sockaddr),
> ```
>
> sizeof(@encode(struct sockaddr)-1)) ==
> 0) {
>
> ```
>                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> ```
>
> 3 warnings generated.
>
> Modules/objc/ObjCPointer.m:134:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/OC_PythonArray.m:356:34:
> warning: conflicting parameter types
> in implementation of
> 'initWithObjects:count:': 'const id *'
> vs 'NSObject* *'
> [-Wmismatched-parameter-types]
>
> -(id)initWithObjects:(NSObject**)objects
> count:(NSUInteger)count
>
> ```
>                   ~~~~~~~~~~ ^
> ```
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:93:46:
> note: previous definition is here
>
> - (instancetype)initWithObjects:(const id [])objects count:(NSUInteger)cnt;
>   / *designated initializer* /
>
>   ```
>                                  ~~~~~ ^
>   ```
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/OC_PythonDictionary.m:377:35:
> warning: conflicting parameter types
> in implementation of
> 'initWithObjects:forKeys:count:':
> 'const id *' vs 'NSObject* *'
> [-Wmismatched-parameter-types]
>
> - (id)initWithObjects:(NSObject**)objects
>
>   ```
>                  ~~~~~~~~~~ ^
>   ```
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSDictionary.h:70:46:
> note: previous definition is here
>
> - (instancetype)initWithObjects:(const id [])objects forKeys:(const id
>   <NSCopying> [])keys
>   count:(NSUInteger)cnt;       /
>   *designated initializer* /
>
>   ```
>                                  ~~~~~ ^
>   ```
>
> Modules/objc/OC_PythonDictionary.m:378:24:
> warning: conflicting parameter types
> in implementation of
> 'initWithObjects:forKeys:count:':
> 'const id<NSCopying> *' vs 'NSObject*
> *' [-Wmismatched-parameter-types]
>
> ```
>       forKeys:(NSObject**)keys
>
>                ~~~~~~~~~~ ^
> ```
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSDictionary.h:70:87:
> note: previous definition is here
>
> - (instancetype)initWithObjects:(const id [])objects forKeys:(const id
>   <NSCopying> [])keys
>   count:(NSUInteger)cnt;       /
>   *designated initializer* /
>
>   ```
>                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
>   ```
>
> 2 warnings generated.
>
> Modules/objc/OC_PythonUnicode.m:297:27:
> warning: conflicting parameter types
> in implementation of
> 'initWithBytes:length:encoding:':
> 'const void *' vs 'void* '
> [-Wmismatched-parameter-types]
>
> -(id)initWithBytes:(void*)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length
> encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
>
> ```
>                 ~~~~~ ^
> ```
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:265:45:
> note: previous definition is here
>
> - (instancetype)initWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)len
>   encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
>
>   ```
>                                ~~~~~~ ^
>   ```
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/selector.m:501:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> Modules/objc/selector.m:772:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> Modules/objc/selector.m:1855:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> 3 warnings generated.
>
> Modules/objc/struct-wrapper.m:1095:5:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> ```
> },
>
> ^
> ```
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/unicode-object.m:205:1:
> warning: missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> Modules/objc/varlist.m:371:1: warning:
> missing field 'tp_finalize'
> initializer
> [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> 1 warning generated.
>
> ld: warning: could not create compact
> unwind for _ffi_call_unix64: does not
> use RBP or RSP based frame
>
> Modules/objc/test/properties.m:24:9:
> warning: Ignore warnings about
> properties in this file.
> [-W#pragma-messages]
>
> ## pragma message "Ignore warnings about properties in this file."
>
> ```
>     ^
> ```
>
> Modules/objc/test/properties.m:28:1:
> warning: no 'assign', 'retain', or
> 'copy' attribute is specified -
> 'assign' is assumed
> [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]
>
> @property id prop4;
>
> ^
>
> Modules/objc/test/properties.m:28:1:
> warning: default property attribute
> 'assign' not appropriate for non-GC
> object [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]
>
> Modules/objc/test/properties.m:30:1:
> warning: no 'assign', 'retain', or
> 'copy' attribute is specified -
> 'assign' is assumed
> [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]
>
> @property(readwrite) id prop6;
>
> ^
>
> Modules/objc/test/properties.m:30:1:
> warning: default property attribute
> 'assign' not appropriate for non-GC
> object [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]
>
> Modules/objc/test/properties.m:35:1:
> warning: no 'assign', 'retain', or
> 'copy' attribute is specified -
> 'assign' is assumed
> [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]
>
> @property(getter=propGetter,setter=propSetter:)
> id prop11;
>
> ^
>
> Modules/objc/test/properties.m:35:1:
> warning: default property attribute
> 'assign' not appropriate for non-GC
> object [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]
>
> 7 warnings generated.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "<string>", line 17, in
> <module>
>
> File
> "/private/var/folders/g2/0ytb_hgx3yz1fcr6dwjdyw8h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging8684618905321973057.tmp/pyobjc-framework-AddressBook/setup.py",
> line 33, in <module>
>
> ```
> for fn in os.listdir('Modules')
> ```
>
> File
> "/private/var/folders/g2/0ytb_hgx3yz1fcr6dwjdyw8h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging8684618905321973057.tmp/pyobjc-framework-AddressBook/pyobjc_setup.py",
> line 441, in setup
>
> ```
> **k
> ```
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py",
> line 108, in setup
>
> ```
> _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
> ```
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/dist.py",
> line 261, in **init**
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/dist.py",
> line 286, in fetch_build_eggs
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources.py",
> line 631, in resolve
>
> ```
> dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
> ```
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources.py",
> line 871, in best_match
>
> ```
> return self.obtain(req, installer)
> ```
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources.py",
> line 883, in obtain
>
> ```
> return installer(requirement)
> ```
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/dist.py",
> line 337, in fetch_build_egg
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
> line 613, in easy_install
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
> line 643, in install_item
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
> line 833, in install_eggs
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
> line 1055, in build_and_install
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
> line 1040, in run_setup
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 50, in run_setup
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 100, in run
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 52, in <lambda>
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/compat.py",
> line 75, in execfile
>
> File "setup.py", line 574, in
> <module>
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py",
> line 148, in setup
>
> ```
> dist.run_commands()
> ```
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py",
> line 955, in run_commands
>
> ```
> self.run_command(cmd)
> ```
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py",
> line 974, in run_command
>
> ```
> cmd_obj.run()
> ```
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py",
> line 161, in run
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py",
> line 147, in call_command
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py",
> line 313, in run_command
>
> ```
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
> ```
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py",
> line 974, in run_command
>
> ```
> cmd_obj.run()
> ```
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/install_lib.py",
> line 10, in run
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 111, in install
>
> ```
> outfiles = self.copy_tree(self.build_dir,
> ```
>
> self.install_dir)
>
> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.2-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/install_lib.py",
> line 35, in copy_tree
>
> File "setup.py", line 271, in
> get_exclusions
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no
> attribute '_install_lib'
>
> Use '/usr/bin/clang' instead of
> 'clang' as the compiler
>
> ---------------------------------------- Cleaning up... Command python setup.py
> egg_info failed with error code 1 in
> /private/var/folders/g2/0ytb_hgx3yz1fcr6dwjdyw8h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging8684618905321973057.tmp/pyobjc-framework-AddressBook Storing debug log for failure in
> /Users/DerKode/.pip/pip.log

Comment: В питоне нет компиляции в традиционном понимании этого слова. Какие именно ошибки возникают? (и как мы должны ответить на вопрос "почему эти модули не работают", не имея никаких данных?)

Comment: ну вы бы хоть ошибки привели. Вдруг у вас винда так называется "Max OS", вы скачали пакеты для Max OS и они поэтому и не работают ))

Comment: Надо же, и вправду компилируется

> Use '/usr/bin/clang' instead of 'clang' as the compiler

clang стоит?

Comment: Да. Он у меня как раз в папке /usr/bin.

Comment: это точно не симлинк на какое-нибудь говно? `which clang` в терминале резолвится в /usr/bin/clang?

Comment: Все верно вроди бы
which clang ответ:
/usr/bin/clang

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю, почему он хочет что-то компилировать, но можно попробовать `env CC=/usr/bin/clang pip3 -U pyobjc`. Альтернативно можно попробовать поставить [вручную](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/install.html#manual-installation) или через `easy_install`.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал переустановить Developer tools командой `xcode-select --install` в терминале. У меня было пару раз, после ОС апдейта, что нужно было принять соглашение, и компиляция модулей вылетала со странной ошибкой. Можно так же проверить что clang вообще запускается и не выдаёт ошибку -- `clang` в терминале и он должен выдать `clang: error: no input files`.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
from subprocess import call

def osx_notification(text, title=""):
    text   = text.replace('"', '\\"')
    title  = title.replace('"', '\\"')
    script = 'display notification "{}" with title "{}"'.format(text, title)
    call(['osascript', '-e', script])

osx_notification('My text', title='My title')
```